# Creating An external Table With Partitions in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partition, bucket

I am trying to creating an external table with Partition below is the reference image i am using.

[image]

Here is what i am intending to do :

I have files flowing into this folder:
[image]

I need to query the external table based on the date  :

eg :

select * from  where _PartitionDate ='';

My specific query is what should i fill in the GCS bucket & source Data partitioning  fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation that Guillaume provided [1], you should click on the `Source data partitioning` box and provide the following link there:

```
gs://datalake-confidential-redacted/ExternalTable_Data/
```

Also, the `Table type` should be **External table**.

Once that is fixed, you should be able to create the table. I have reproduced the issue on my own and it is working.

[1] -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs#hive-partitioning-options

Answer (score 0):

This [part of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs#hive-partitioning-options) should help you. You need to check the `Source data partitioning` and then to fill in your prefix URI such as

```
gs://datalake-confidential-redacted/ExternalTable_Data/{dt:DATE}
```

And then, use this `dt` field as any field in your queries

```
SELECT *
FROM `externale-table`
WHERE dt = "2020-01-10"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response,  I have tried inputting the same parameter into the prefix URI & it fails with the error as below:

Invalid source URI: gs:///bigstore/datalake-confidential-redacted/ExternalTable_Data/{dt:DATE}

Comment: there is 3/ after the gs:, is it normal?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response, It is only gs://datalake-confidential-redacted/ExternalTable_Data/{dt:DATE}

Comment: Created a teraform script for the above. It is cleared. There is a issue with custom Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Wizard has an issue with this approch. Once we used Teraform scripts it has been successful. It mandates a need to mark HIVE partition to custom & once the date column is created it is added as column into the table. there by allowing to query.